# How to link views content nodes to custom URL

Tags: 7, views, ajax, display-suite

I have nodes in a view using a custom view mode (using Display Suite).  I'm doing some AJAX stuff when the user clicks on a particular node, so I need to wrap the nodes in a custom URL, like somenode/nojs/(nid).

I feel like I should be able to do this in Views, since fields can link to the content.  Is there a way to get the node to link to a custom URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it in Display Suite using tokens.

EDIT:

For getting my node of a particular view mode to be clickable, I was able to set it in my node's display, in the view mode, and below the fields under "Custom Wrappers", I switched the "Add Link" box to "Tokens", and entered my URL with the [node:nid] token.

However, that just added an onClick handler to my node wrapper, so it wasn't useful for the purpose of making my node clickable for an AJAX callback.  I had to do override my template file and works fine.

Comment: Can you expand this to explain how you added the token, etc, particularly if it is different than @redhatlab's answer.

Comment: Yes, but to stay within the context of my AJAX-related question, I need to see if this is going to work.  I see the method I chose adds an onClick() handler to the node div, instead of creating an a tag/href element.  If this doesn't work, I may need to try redhatlab's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get the node link in a custom URL, but you can overwrite the output of the nid field.

Steps:

***1. Add NID field***

[image]

***2. Hide field (this might change depending in your setup)***

[image]

***3. Go to the overwrite section and overwrite the NID output***

[image]

***4. The rest is up to you. You can display a field as a link and add the NID field as a replacemente pattern or use it as is.***